# How to use an instance of prototype object instead of JSON in knockoutjs

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js

In Knockout JS example @ http://knockoutjs.com/examples/gridEditor.html

In the view model we have code as below

```
self.addGift = function() {
    self.gifts.push({
        name: "",
        price: ""
    });
};
```

and

```
var viewModel = new GiftModel([
    { name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"},
    { name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"}
]);
```

The problem is the anonymous JSON object. Is there any way I can pass an instance of class and get this working? like using `new Gift()`

```
self.addGift = function() {
        self.gifts.push(new Gift());
    };
```

and

```
var viewModel = new GiftModel([
    new Gift(){ name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"},
    new Gift(){ name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"}
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh my... 
consider this http://jsfiddle.net/UZJL7/
first of all create gift model then

```
function Gift(opts){
 this.name= ko.observable(opts.name)
 this.price= ko.observable(opts.price)
}
```

and move params inside brackets

```
  new Gift({ name: "Tall Hat", price: "39.95"}),
  new Gift({ name: "Long Cloak", price: "120.00"})
```